When I send requests from different domain to ASP.NET Core Web API, http only cookie aren't sent?
When I send request from another domain to server, the http-only cookie aren't sent to the server.
I get http only cookie while login. Everything is ok from the same domain, but when I send request from another domain to server, the http only cookie aren't sent to the server.

Http-only cookies are designed to be inaccessible to client-side scripts, such as JavaScript, and can only be sent to the server in HTTP requests. A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it's only sent to the server.
This means that even if you receive an HTTP-only cookie during login from one domain, it won't be accessible to JavaScript on another domain.
When you send a request from another domain to the server, the browser should still include any relevant cookies for that domain in the request headers, including HTTP-only cookies. However, if the request is being made from client-side JavaScript running on a different domain, the HTTP-only cookies won't be accessible to that JavaScript code.
Besides, the cookie is based on domain, no matter it http-only or not. If your server make a cookie to aaa.com domain, if you access it from bbb.com to the server, the cookie still will not send to the server, since the browser will just send request with the cookie if you access aaa.com website(the cookie is for aaa.com not bbb.com), even aaa.com and bbb.com is the same server.
